# Instalar JDK no linux ubuntu

Tags: linux

Estou tentando instalar o JDK para poder instalar o NetBeans.

Segue minha tentativa de instalação do JDK:

Versão do Java (Java -version):

> java version "1.7.0_95" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4)
>   (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   24.95-b01, mixed mode)

Comando de instalação do JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Saida do comando de instalação:

> kleber@magneto:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk
>   Lendo listas de
>   pacotes... 
>   Pronto Construindo árvore de dependências
>   Lendo informação de estado... 
>   Pronto Alguns pacotes não puderam ser instalados. Isto pode significar que você solicitou uma situação
>   impossível ou, se você está usando a distribuição instável, que alguns
>   pacotes requeridos não foram criados ainda ou foram retirados da
>   "Incoming". A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:
>
> Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:  default-jdk :
>   Depende: openjdk-7-jdk (>= 7~u3-2.1.1) E: Impossível corrigir
>   problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.

Diz que depende do `openjdk` então executo o comando para instalar:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Saída do comando:

> kleber@magneto:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre  Lendo listas de
>   pacotes... Pronto Construindo árvore de dependências        Lendo
>   informação de estado... Pronto openjdk-7-jre já é a versão mais nova.
>   0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos
>   e 0 não atualizados.

Alguém sabe o que devo fazer para conseguir instalar o JDK?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas será que o comando não é `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`? Pelo que eu entendi, ele precisa do kit de desenvolvimento (JDK) não do *runtime* (JRE)

Comment: @Gomiero rodei esse comando e deu ( Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 openjdk-7-jdk : Depende: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u85-2.6.1-5)
                 Recomenda: libxt-dev mas não será instalado
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.
)

Comment: Encontrei esse link que talvez possa ajudar: [Como instalar o Java no Ubuntu com apt-get](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-o-java-no-ubuntu-com-apt-get-pt)

Comment: Execute no terminal: `sudo apt-get install -f` e rode os comando para instalar o que você precisa novamente. Mais uma coisa, antes de executar este comando atualize o seu repositorio com `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Quando usava linux, eu instalava o jdk da oracle mesmo, bastava adicionar a PPA `ppa:webupd8team/java` e depois de atualizar o repositorio do sistema, rodava um `apt-get install oracle-jdkX-installer` onde X é a versão do JDK. Dai, a ppa baixava e instalava tanto a jdk quanto a jre, e ainda registrava nos navegadores. Nunca tive problema algum em nenhuma das versoes do ubuntu, desde a 8 ate a 14, que foi a ultima que instalei.

Comment: `apt-cache search jdk` para ver todos os pacotes relacionados ao jdk, selecione o mais recente e faça: `sudo apt-get install pacoteatual`, acredito que seja: `sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer`

Answer (score 2):

- Faça o [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) do **.tar.gz**
- Execute o comando **tar** para descompactar o arquivo baixado:

> **tar -xvf** jdk-8u77-linux-i586.tar.gz

- Agora, crie uma pasta e mova os arquivos descompactados para a pasta criada:

> sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
>    sudo mv ./jdk1.8.0 /usr/lib/jvm/

- Execute:

> sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java" 1
>   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac" 1
>   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javaws" 1

- Execute o comando abaixo para aplicar as permissões de execução:

> sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
>   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
>   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
>   sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0

- O **update-alternatives** permite a instalação de multiplas versões e possibilita alternar entre elas:

> sudo update-alternatives --config javac
>   sudo update-alternatives --config javaws

- Execute o comando abaixo para verificar a instalação e versão que está em uso:

> java -version

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso o java do repositório WebUpd8. Uso desde o Ubuntu 10.04 e nunca tive problema.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

Pra verificar se instalou certo:

```
java -version
```

E depois:

```
javac -version
```

Feito, basta prosseguir com a instalação do NetBeans.